# iOSでコードからWifiのon/offをコントロールできますか

Tags: ios, swift

現在バックグラウンドで端末のWifiをOnまたはOffにする機能を持ったアイフォンアプリをSwiftを使って作成しようとしています。
そこで質問です。iOSでは端末の設定をコードから変更するということは可能なのでしょうか。
できるのであれば、方法を教えて下さい。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: iOSアプリからは端末の設定を変更することはできないと思います。
iOSの設定に対してできることは、
「設定アプリを起動(位置情報サービス, プッシュ通知, モバイルデータ通信などのON/OFFが手動で変更可能)」, 「BluetoothがOFFのときにアラート出す」などがあります。
ただ、Wi-Fiに関する画面の表示はできないと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
できないのですね、残念です。ありがとうございました。